# Reciprocal Lattice of a non-bravais lattice

Tags: crystals

Is a [reciprocal lattice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice) defined for non-Bravais lattices? I'm trying to work out one for [HCP structure](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=hcp+structure) and not figuring it out.

Comment: You should show research effort in your question.

Answer (score -1):

The simple HCP lattice is just a hexagonal lattice with a base. Compare to FCC and BCC crystals, which can be derived from the simple cubic lattice by adding a base.

Comment: I treated BCC as a SC with a basis, and worked out the cross products of SC vectors and basis vectors independently. It resulted in an FCC. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yep. You can do the same for the hexagonal lattice with a base.

Comment: It did not work. I did the following: a,b,c are primitives of the simple hexagonal, 0 and A = a/3+b/3+c/2 are basis vectors. Let B = A-b which is a basis vector for a neighboring cell. A cross B is not a basis in the reciprocal lattice. HELP ME,,,

Comment: @kalkanistovinko you should add a detailed explanation of your previous comment as an edit to your question.